# How to resolve modules error with arm64 device (Titanium app)

Tags: ios, titanium, arm64, titanium-sdk

When i try to build and run titanium app for ios with titanium cli (titanium build -f -p ios) I receive the following error:

> [ERROR] Error: The app is using native modules that do not support
> arm64 simulators and you are on an arm64 device:
>
> - com.shareourideas.locale
> - com.omorandi
> - ti.reviewdialog
> - com.mfogg.squarecamera
> - av.imageview
>   at iOSBuilder.invokeXcodeBuild

The build is created but when I try to launch the app on the simulator via xCode the app freezes on Launch Screen.

I try to remove these modules from tiapp.xml file, error does not occur but the app keeps stopping on the splash screen. So I assume that the two problems are not related to each other.

how can i fix the error related to the modules

-------GENERAL INFO--------

```
Operating System   
Name                        = macOS   
Version      = 11.5.2   
Architecture                = 64bit   
CPUs     = 8   
Memory                      = 8.0GB
            
Node.js   
Node.js Version             = 16.13.0   
npm Version   = 8.1.0
            
Titanium CLI   
CLI Version                 = 5.4.1   
node-appc Version = 1.1.3
            
Titanium SDKs
  10.1.1.GA
  Version                   = 10.1.1
  Platforms                 = iphone, android
  git Hash                  = 2448cfa671
  git Timestamp             = 11/18/2021 17:12
  node-appc Version         = 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Modules:**

The `arm64 simulators` warning/error just means that you can't use arm64 simulators (e.g. on a M1) unless you update the modules. That just means that you have to recompile them or check the github repos if there is already an update or fork with a newer version.

If not: create an issue in the repo if you can't recompile it yourself.

**Crash:**

Try run building your app with `--log-level trace` and check if you see other output or errors. Sometimes it also helps to build for Android and see if there is an error.

Feel free to join the Titanium Slack (tislack.org/) and join the #helpme channel.

Answer (score 0):

Find your Terminal application in Finder, and right click and select "Get Info". Underneath "Copyright" there's an option for "Open using Rosetta". Select this option and now open the terminal.
Copy the command that Titanium runs to build the application (ti build -- ... etc) and paste in the new terminal, it should now ignore the errors and run in the simulator.